# Kotlin Android Studio - ListView In Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I couldn't implement list view in Fragment. I have just a ListView and ArrayList. My ArrayList is a String and takes 5 name.

```
class GroupFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): GroupFragment {
            return GroupFragment() } }

    var arrayList= ArrayList<String>()
    private lateinit var Adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group, container, false)
        val activity = activity as Context

        val listview = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view)
        arrayList.add("Ajay")
        arrayList.add("Vijay")  
        arrayList.add("Prakash")  
        arrayList.add("Rohan")  
        arrayList.add("Vijay") 

        Adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList )

        listview.adapter = ChatAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList)

        return view
    }



class ChatAdapter(var mCtx: Context, var resources:Int, var items:List<String>):ArrayAdapter<String>(mCtx, resources, items) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val layoutInflater:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
            val view:View = layoutInflater.inflate(resources, null)
            val titleTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView)
            var mItem: String = items[position]
            titleTextView.text = mItem
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
        }

    }
}
```

My code as above but it returns nothing. I didn't understand why ?? Is it a problem "Adapter" ?? Is there any problem **context** ??

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to determine the problem. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are u sure your array isn't empty?

Comment: I edited again. Could you check it please? Where is the problem? @MikeM.

Comment: No, it is not empty. @ImanX

Comment: You're not using that `ArrayAdapter` at all, so you can just remove that line. Aside from that, though, we're still gonna need more information; at least the `ChatAdapter` class, and possibly more. You'll know exactly what to include in your question after you've put together a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for my asking problems. I shared ChatAdapter class. @MikeM.

Comment: The first thing I see is that you need to `return view` from `getView()`, instead of `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)`.

Comment: I didint work @MikeM.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that was the only issue. That's why we need a [mcve]. Please read through that page I've linked.

Comment: Actually, when I debugging it didn't inside in ChatAdapter class'

Comment: If no methods in your `Adapter` are being called, then that `ListView` isn't actually getting loaded and laid out.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try directly

```
listview.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList )
```